# Bootstrap Grid fit images to same height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My problem is that the heights of rows / columns does not fit. The first column has the class col-sm-8 and the second the class col-sm-4

The second class col-sm-4 has another two rows, each with col-sm-12 classes.

I have looked for some Masonry similar jQuery Plugins but I want to stay at CSS. How can I solve this heights and keep responsivity?

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row" style="padding-bottom:30px;">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
   <img src="http://xtc.he-webpack.de/templates/JTL-Shop3-Tiny/banners/inteledison.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="border-radius: 4px; border:1px solid #ff6600"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
     <img src="http://xtc.he-webpack.de/templates/JTL-Shop3-Tiny/banners/inteledison.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="border-radius: 4px; border:1px solid #ff6600"/>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
     <img src="http://xtc.he-webpack.de/templates/JTL-Shop3-Tiny/banners/bare.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="border-radius: 4px; border:1px solid #ff6600" />
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <img src="http://xtc.he-webpack.de/templates/JTL-Shop3-Tiny/banners/esp8622.jpg" class="img-responsive"  style="border-radius: 4px; border:1px solid #ff6600" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <img src="http://xtc.he-webpack.de/templates/JTL-Shop3-Tiny/banners/raspb2b.jpg" class="img-responsive"  style="border-radius: 4px; border:1px solid #ff6600" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <img src="http://xtc.he-webpack.de/templates/JTL-Shop3-Tiny/banners/beaglebone.jpg" class="img-responsive"  style="border-radius: 4px; border:1px solid #ff6600" />
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```